# how to add after the word, with regex

Tags: regex

Before :

> 4510620012032718
> 4510620012032344
> 4510620012034544

After :

> 4510620012032718 01/01 202
> 4510620012032344 01/01 202
> 4510620012034544 01/01 202

how to add after the word, with notepad ++ or regex ?

Comment: Find `([0-9]+)` and replace `\1 01/01 202`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to do this.

```
Find: ^\d+\K
Replace:  01/01 202
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\d)(?=\b)
```

Try this.Replace by `01/01 202`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/10